# Rendering jinja2 blocks as json

Tags: python, jinja2

I've created a jinja2 template that should support both standalone rendering and ajax rendering.
The template looks like:

```
{% if is_ajax %}{% extends 'ajax.html' %}{% else %}{% extends 'site.html' %}{% endif %}
{% block title %}The Title{% endblock %}
{% block body %}The body{% endblock %}
```

site.html works fine, but I failed to create ajax.html that will render the title and body blocks as json. I tried something like:

```
{
    "copy":"{% block body %}Default Body{% endblock %}",
    "title":"{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}",
}
```

But this of course doesn't convert the blocks to json.

I've also tried to use Template.blocks to create the json using python, but this method requires manual rendering of each block, which doesn't feel like the right way of doing it.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd not use a template to generate JSON, not when the `json` module would do a much better job of it and would handle quoting better too.

Comment: I agree, and also tried this, but this means i have to manually render the blocks, and in fact re-implement part of jinja. it works, but there must be a better way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using the `self.block_name()` directive. The `dumps` is actually 'json.dumps' passed into the template.

```
{
    "copy" : {{ dumps(self.copy()) | safe }},
    "title" : {{ dumps(self.title()) | safe }}
}
```

Comment: So this is `ajax.html`?